# How can we read $\partial \Omega$ (boundary of a domain $\Omega$)?

Tags: definite-integrals, notation, terminology

Simple question: how do we read "$\partial \Omega$" (I mean in spoken language)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why anyone downvoted this.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, "The boundary of $\Omega$".

Comment: How do you pronounce $\Omega$ ?

Comment: "Omega"? Normally it's obvious that it's a capital omega, but if necessary, "capital Omega".

Comment: Thanks ! (but it was a (stupid) joke, you can ignore my comment, sorry for this )

Comment: Given the multilinguistic nature of mathematics, asking how to pronounce a Greek letter is entirely reasonable... plenty of mathematicians don't seem to have the education to manage this!

Comment: My question was obviously for the $\partial$ symbol.

Comment: @Chappers  what is the original pronunciation of $\partial$ in Greek?

Comment: @nonlinearthought ∂ is not a Greek letter; it appears to be a mathematical coinage from the time of Legendre and others: http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html . The symbol is apparently from the cursive form of the Cyrillic letter equivalent to Roman "d", presumably because it was another distinctive d-like form the printers had, just as Cantor later used $\aleph$ for certain particular sets.